# ASP.Net MVC 3 - Password Protect View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, passwords

Visual Studio 2010 - MVC 3

I have an admin section of an asp.net mvc application which I want to restrict access to. The application will not use accounts so I won't be using an administrator role or user to authorize access for example.

I want the section to be accessible by the entry of a single password. There will be a number of actions in this section. I have set up an admin controller which redirects to a number of different views so basically any view which this controller controls needs to be restricted.

I would also like it so that the password only needs to be entered once for a session, so when the browser is closed and reopened the password would need to be re-entered.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you have a View folder called `Protected` (as your controller), and you have several Actions that points to several Views, I would do this:

- decorate the controller/actions with an Action Filter, for example: `[SimpleMembership]`
- on that action filter, just check the existence and the contents of a Session Variable
- redirect to a `SignIn` if not the correct one

in code:

```
public class SimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //redirect if not authenticated
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["myApp-Authentication"] == null ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session["myApp-Authentication"] != "123")
        {
            //use the current url for the redirect
            string redirectOnSuccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            //send them off to the login page
            string redirectUrl = string.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess);
            string loginUrl = "/Protected/SignIn" + redirectUrl;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

and your controller

```
public class ProtectedController : Controller
{
    [SimpleMembership]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SignIn()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(string pwd)
    {
        if (pwd == "123")
        {
            Session["myApp-Authentication"] = "123";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

if you want to decorate the entire `controller`, you need to move the `SignIn` methods outside as to reach there, you would need to be authenticated.

---

**Source code:**

You can **download** the simple MVC3 solution http://cl.ly/JN6B or fell free to view the code on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/balexandre/Stackoverflow-Question-12378445).

Answer (score 1):

I would use Forms authentication.
and then add the [Authorize] attribute just  to the controller or individual actions you want to restrict.
Then you will need a way to log in ect. 
look [Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) for info on forms authentication hope that helps

You could always create your own authentication system saving the user name and password in a config file, or database or something. You can override the [Authorize] or create your own action filter and do with it as you wish.if you didn't want to get into the full forms authentication.